# Building a GTD Productivity App Designed through Test Driven Development (TDD)

Tags: unit-testing, error-handling, rust

First, thanks so much for looking at my code. Over the past decade, I have tried every task management apps imaginable. I finally realized that the only way I would ever find my perfect productivity system is if I build it myself.

To this end, I am creating ClearHeadTodo, a productivity app that seeks to bring the [GTD](https://gettingthingsdone.com/) model of productivity using entirely rust if possible.

While for now i'm only focused on the Command Line Interface (CLI) my ultimate goal is to make this a modular piece of software where the core productivity system works no matter what medium you are utilizing (GUI or CLI)

**The Question: Control Flow Best-Practices for Testing and Scalability**

**The Code: 2 Main Files**
For now, most of this work is broken into two files (lib.rs and main.rs respectively)

- lib.rs contains the main logic for the Task List
- While main.rs contains the CLI struct which the user actually interacts with to alter the task objects.

**Current Code Status**
For right now, users can only create tasks. Tasks have a name, priority, and completion status.

- This is all loaded to and from a vector using a .csv to reduce database complexity

I'm very proud to say that everything works from all my testing, however, now that the code is all together, it feels... difficult to scale the code base since the main command loop is basically just a huge match statement.

I want to use best-practices like the result data type, but i am having trouble formatting the code in such a way that would propagate the result of each function properly to the end of the main command line.

Specifically, whenever i try using the `?`, it throws an error saying that i'm not using the proper type (even though you can see there are several results in this code)

**Operation** all work is done through just running the main rust build with any arguments,
so `cargo run create_task` will create a new task which can be shown with `cargo run list_task
Dependencies are light, just serde, along with the CSV package for it to load and unload the task list through the serializer
Cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "clear_head_todo"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["Mantis-Shrimp <dargondab9@gmail.com>"]
edition = "2018"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
csv = "1.1"
serde = { version = "1.0", features = ["derive"] }
```

Main.rs

```
use std::io::{self, Write};
use std::io::stdout;
use clear_head_todo::TaskList;
use clear_head_todo::PriEnum;
use std::path::Path;

pub struct CLI{
    pub pattern: Option<String>,
    pub index: Option<String>,
    pub input: Option<String>,
    pub task_vec: TaskList
}

impl CLI {
        pub fn parse_arguments(&mut self) {
            match self.pattern.as_ref().unwrap_or(
                &"no command given".to_string()) as &str{
            "create_task" | "create" | "ct" | "new_task" | "new" =>
                self.task_vec
                .create_task(),
            "list_tasks" | "lt" | "list" | "list_all" =>
                self.task_vec.print_task_list(std::io::stdout()).unwrap_or(()),
            "remove_task" | "remove" | "rt" | "delete_task" | "delete" =>
                self.task_vec
                .remove_task(
                    self.index.as_ref()
                    .unwrap()
                    .to_string()
                    .parse::<usize>()
                    .unwrap(), 
                    io::stdout())
                    .expect("invalid index"),
            "complete_task" | "complete" | "mark_complete" =>
                self.task_vec.tasks[
                self.index.as_ref()
                .unwrap()
                .parse::<usize>()
                .unwrap()]
                .mark_complete(),
            "change_priority" | "cp" | "new_priority" | "np" =>
                self.task_vec.tasks[
                self.index.as_ref()
                .unwrap()
                .parse::<usize>()
                .unwrap()]
                .change_priority(
                        &self.input.as_ref().unwrap()[..]),
            "rename_task" | "rename" | "name" | "r" =>
                self.task_vec.tasks[
                self.index.as_ref()
               .unwrap()
               .parse::<usize>()
               .unwrap()]
               .rename_task(
                    self.input.as_ref()
                   .unwrap()),
            _ => return
            };
    }
    pub fn cli_list_tasks(&self, mut writer: impl std::io::Write){
        self.task_vec.print_task_list(writer).unwrap_or(());
    }
}
fn main() {

    println!("starting program");
    
    let mut main_cli: CLI = CLI{
        pattern : std::env::args().nth(1),
        index: std::env::args().nth(2),
        input: std::env::args().nth(3),
        task_vec: TaskList{
            tasks: vec![]
        }
    };

    main_cli.task_vec.load_tasks("tasks.csv").unwrap();
    
    main_cli.parse_arguments();

    main_cli.task_vec.load_csv("tasks.csv").unwrap();
    
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn cli_creation_test () {
        let mut test_cli = CLI {
            pattern: None, 
            index: None,
            input: None,
            task_vec: TaskList{tasks: vec![]}, 

        };
        assert!(test_cli.pattern == None);
        assert!(test_cli.index == None);
        assert!(test_cli.input == None);
        assert!(test_cli.task_vec.tasks.len() == 0);
        test_cli.parse_arguments();
    }

    #[test]
    fn cli_task_creation_test () {
        let mut test_cli = CLI {
            pattern: Some("create_task".to_string()), 
            index: None,
            input: None,
            task_vec: TaskList{tasks: vec![]}, 

        };
        test_cli.parse_arguments();
        assert!(test_cli.task_vec.tasks.len() == 1);
        assert!(test_cli.task_vec.tasks[0].name == "Test Task");
        assert!(test_cli.task_vec.tasks[0].completed == false);
        assert!(test_cli.task_vec.tasks[0].priority == PriEnum::Optional);
    }

    #[test]
    fn cli_task_list_test () {
        //let mut good_result = Vec::new();
        let mut test_cli = CLI {
            pattern: Some("list_tasks".to_string()), 
            index: None,
            input: None,
            task_vec: TaskList{tasks: vec![]}, 

        };

        test_cli.parse_arguments();
    }
}
```

Lib.rs (logical center of the app)

```
use std::error::Error;
use std::io::{Error as OtherError, ErrorKind};
use std::fmt;
use csv::Reader;
use csv::Writer;
use std::path::{Path, PathBuf};
use std::env;
use std::str::FromStr;
use serde::ser::{Serialize, SerializeStruct, Serializer};
use serde::Serialize as AltSerialize;

pub struct TaskList {
    pub tasks: Vec<Task>
}

#[derive(PartialEq)]
#[derive(Debug)]
#[repr(u8)]
#[derive(AltSerialize)]
pub enum PriEnum {
    Critical = 1,
    High = 2,
    Medium = 3,
    Low = 4,
    Optional = 5,
}

impl fmt::Display for PriEnum {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        let printable: &str = match *self {
            PriEnum::Critical => "Critical",
            PriEnum::High => "High",
            PriEnum::Medium => "Medium",
            PriEnum::Low => "Low",
            PriEnum::Optional => "Optional"
        };
        write!(f, "{}", printable)
    }
}

impl Serialize for Task {
    fn serialize<S>(&self, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error> 
    where
            S: Serializer, 
        {
            let mut s = serializer.serialize_struct("Task", 3)?;
            s.serialize_field("name", &self.name)?;
            s.serialize_field("priority", &self.priority)?;
            s.serialize_field("completed", &self.completed)?;
            s.end()
        }
}
 
pub fn parse_priority(expr: &str) -> Result<PriEnum, String> {
    match expr.to_ascii_lowercase().trim() {
        "1" | "critical" | "crit" | "c" => Ok(PriEnum::Critical),
        "2" | "high" | "hi" | "h" => Ok(PriEnum::High),
        "3" | "medium" | "med" | "m" => Ok(PriEnum::Medium),
        "4" | "low" | "lo" | "l" => Ok(PriEnum::Low),
        "5" | "optional" | "opt" | "o" => Ok(PriEnum::Optional),
        "" => Ok(PriEnum::Optional), //defaults to this
        _ => Err(format!("Invalid priority value")),
    }
}

#[derive(PartialEq, Debug)]
pub struct Task {
    pub name: String,
    pub completed: bool,
    pub priority: PriEnum, 
}

impl TaskList {
    //load tasks from either tasks.csv or testTasks.csv using the file_name
    pub fn load_tasks(&mut self, file_name: &str) -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
        let pathbuf = env::current_dir().unwrap().join("data").join(file_name);
        let mut rdr: Reader<std::fs::File> = Reader::from_path(pathbuf)?;
        for result in rdr.records() { 
            let record = result?;
            let new_task = Task {
                name: record[0].to_string(),
                completed: FromStr::from_str(&record[2])?,
                priority : parse_priority(&record[1])?,
            };
            self.tasks.push(new_task);
        }
        Ok(())
    }

    pub fn load_csv(&mut self, file_name: &str) -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
        let pathbuf = env::current_dir().unwrap().join("data").join(file_name);
        let mut wtr: Writer<std::fs::File> = Writer::from_path(pathbuf)?;
        for index in 0..=self.tasks.len()-1{
            wtr.serialize::<_>(&self.tasks[index]).unwrap();
        }
        Ok(())
    }

    pub fn create_task(&mut self) {
        let new_task: Task = Task {
            name: String::from("Test Task"),
            completed: false,
            priority: PriEnum::Optional,
        };
        self.tasks.push(new_task);
    }
    
    pub fn print_task_list(&self, mut writer: impl std::io::Write)->
    Result<(), std::io::Error> {
        if self.tasks.is_empty()==true{
            return Err(OtherError::new(ErrorKind::Other, "list is empty"));
        } else{
            for index in 0..=self.tasks.len()-1 {
                writeln!(writer, "{index},{name},{priority},{completed}",
                        index = index,
                        name = self.tasks[index].name,
                        priority = self.tasks[index].priority,
                        completed = self.tasks[index].completed)?;
            }
        }
        Ok(())
    }
    
    pub fn remove_task(&mut self, index: usize, mut writer: impl std::io::Write) -> 
    Result<(), std::io::Error>  {
        if index < self.tasks.len() {
            writeln!(writer, "Deleted {name} Task", 
                     name = self.tasks[index].name)?; 
            self.tasks.remove(index);
            return Ok(());
        }
        else {
            return Err(OtherError::new(ErrorKind::Other, "Invalid Index for Deletion"));
        }
    }

} //end 'impl TaskList'
 

impl Task {
    pub fn rename_task(&mut self, new_task_name: &String) {
        self.name = new_task_name.to_owned();
    }
    
    pub fn mark_complete(&mut self) {
        self.completed = true;
    }
    
    pub fn change_priority(&mut self, new_priority: &str) {
        let new_pri = parse_priority(new_priority);
        match new_pri {
            Ok(i) => self.priority = i,
            Err(err) => println!("{}", err),
        };
        
    }
   
} //end 'impl Task'

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;
    
    #[test]
    fn task_creation_test() {
        let mut test_task_list = TaskList{tasks: vec![]}; 
        test_task_list.create_task();
        let test_task = &test_task_list.tasks[0];
        assert!(test_task.name == "Test Task");
        assert!(test_task.completed == false);
        assert!(test_task.priority == PriEnum::Optional);
        assert!(&test_task_list.tasks[0] == test_task);
    }
    
    #[test]
    fn task_rename_test() {
        let mut test_task_list = TaskList{tasks: vec![]}; 
        test_task_list.create_task();         
        let test_task = &mut test_task_list.tasks[0];
        test_task.rename_task(&"Changed Name".to_string());
        assert!(test_task.name == "Changed Name");
    }
    
    #[test]
    fn task_completion_test() {
        let mut test_task_list = TaskList{tasks: vec![]}; 
        test_task_list.create_task();
        let test_task = &mut test_task_list.tasks[0];
        test_task.mark_complete();
        assert!(test_task.completed == true);
    }
    
    #[test]
    fn task_successful_removal_test() {
        let mut test_task_list = TaskList{tasks: vec![]};
        let mut good_result = Vec::new();
        test_task_list.create_task();
        test_task_list.remove_task(0, &mut good_result).unwrap();
        assert!(test_task_list.tasks.is_empty());
        assert_eq!(&good_result[..], "Deleted Test Task Task\n".as_bytes());
    }
    
    #[test]
    fn task_removal_fail_test(){
        let mut test_task_list = TaskList{tasks: vec![]};
        let mut bad_result = Vec::new();
        let error = test_task_list.remove_task(0, &mut bad_result).unwrap_err();
        assert_eq!(error.to_string(), "Invalid Index for Deletion");
    }

    #[test]
    fn task_reprioritize_test() {
        let mut test_task_list = TaskList{tasks: vec![]}; 
        test_task_list.create_task();
        let test_task = &mut test_task_list.tasks[0];
        println!("{}", test_task.name);
        test_task.change_priority("4");
        assert!(test_task.priority == PriEnum::Low);
        test_task.change_priority("3");
        assert!(test_task.priority == PriEnum::Medium);
        test_task.change_priority("2");
        assert!(test_task.priority == PriEnum::High);
        test_task.change_priority("1");
        assert!(test_task.priority == PriEnum::Critical);
        test_task.change_priority("6");
        assert!(test_task.priority == PriEnum::Critical); //should NOT change on bad input
    }
    
    #[test]
    fn task_print_fail_test(){
        let test_task_list = TaskList{tasks: vec![]};
        let mut bad_result = Vec::new();
        let error = test_task_list.print_task_list(&mut bad_result).unwrap_err();
        assert_eq!(error.to_string(), "list is empty");
    }
    #[test]
    fn task_print_full_test(){
        let mut test_task_list = TaskList{tasks: vec![]};
        let mut good_result = Vec::new();
        test_task_list.create_task();
        test_task_list.print_task_list(&mut good_result).unwrap();
        assert_eq!(&good_result[..], "0,Test Task,Optional,false\n".as_bytes());
    }
    
    #[test]
    fn load_from_csv_sucessful_test(){
        let mut test_task_list = TaskList{tasks: vec![]};
        test_task_list.load_tasks("testTasks.csv").unwrap();
        let test_task = &test_task_list.tasks[0];
        assert!(test_task.name == "test csv task");
        assert!(test_task.completed == false);
        assert!(test_task.priority == PriEnum::Optional);
    }

    #[test]
    fn load_from_csv_fail_test(){
        let mut test_task_list = TaskList{tasks: vec![]};
        let error = test_task_list.load_tasks("bad_file").unwrap_err();
        assert!(error.to_string().contains("(os error 2)"));
    }
    
    #[test]
    fn load_to_csv_successful_test(){
        let mut test_task_list = TaskList{tasks: vec![]};
        test_task_list.create_task();
        test_task_list.tasks[0].rename_task(&"test csv task".to_string());
        test_task_list.load_csv("testTask.csv").unwrap();
        let rdr = Reader::from_path(
            env::current_dir().unwrap().join("data").join("testTasks.csv").as_path())
            .unwrap();
        let mut iter = rdr.into_records();
        if let Some(result) = iter.next() {
            let record = result.unwrap();
            assert_eq!(record, vec!["test csv task", "Optional", "false"]);
        }
    }

}
```

Again, Thank you for taking the time to look at this, everything should run if you put these in a cargo project, if even cargo test fails, please send me the error code

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. Can you please add your `Cargo.toml` for your dependencies and library names?

Comment: hey @Zeta I added the Cargo.toml, I just use serde, and the CSV derivative to load and unload data between runs using the serializer. Thanks so much for taking the time.